# Install missing R packages when running in bash mode

Tags: r

Frequently I am running `R` scripts in bash mode. My script is called `981_conduct_regression.R`. In this script, I call required packages with

```
if(!require(<package>)){
  install.packages("<package>")
  library(<package>)
}
```

Now when I call the script from bash mode (on Ubuntu 14.04), the script (shown below) fails to install the packages:

```
Loading required package: gridExtra
Installing package into ‘/home/michael/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error in contrib.url(repos, type) : 
  trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror
Calls: source ... eval -> eval -> install.packages -> grep -> contrib.url
In addition: Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘gridExtra’
Execution halted
```

What do I have to change for my idea to work?

**Edit**: Here is the `.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash

Rscript Code/981_conduct_regression.R
```

Comment: What is `981_conduct_regression.R`? It is better if you keep things self-contained. Less confusing. Give a minimal named example script in your question, run it, then give the output.

Comment: Thats the name of the RScript.

Comment: On a side note, if you put #!/usr/bin/env Rscript as the first line of your R file, and chmod u+x the file, you can just run it, rather than depending on a separate bash script to execute the intended script. http://stackoverflow.com/a/969680/1834057

Comment: Yes I know, thanks. But commonly, we pass arguments to the RScript. I don't do here because it's not necessary to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify your CRAN mirror; interactively in R, run

```
chooseCRANmirror()
```

to pick an appropriate mirror, then

```
options("repos")
```

to see the resulting URL. You can add this permanently to your configuration in `~/.Rprofile`:

```
local({r <- getOption("repos")
   r["CRAN"] <- "<URL from above goes here>" 
   options(repos=r)
})
```

Comment: please, should I add this chunk of code at the beginning of the R script, or within batch file?

Comment: You should add it to your `~/.Rprofile`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Stephen Kitt's suggestion, this resolved the problem:

```
~ $ cat .Rprofile 
local({r <- getOption("repos")
   r["CRAN"] <- "https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/CRAN/" 
   options(repos=r)
})
```